# Java Method to check if keyword surrounded by HTML title-tag

Tags: java, html, regex, tags

I am curently trying to write a method, which checks within a textfile if a specific word is encapsulated by specific charachter-sets. For instance, if my keyword is "blablabla", and the char set are html title-tags, 
(e.g.

```
 <h2> blabla </h2>
```

), the method is supposed to return true. However, the keyword itself can be surrounded by different keywords (e.g.

```
<h2> something something blabla in the month of may </h2>
```

) in which case the method still has to return true, since the keyword is still surrounded by the charset defined.
Here is what I allready have:

```
    public static Boolean KeywordIsInTitle(String text, String keywordInText){
        boolean isInTitle = false;
        if( text.contains(keywordInText) == true){
            /*Here is wehre I am stuck....
             * */

            isInTitle = true;}
        return isInTitle;
    }
```

I have been looking at regex and pattern matching for an hour or so but nothing works, and I have to admit I don't ffel very comfortable and very familiar with theses concepts yet...
 Can anyone help? thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This method should return true only. However no need for ==true in the if check.

Comment: you want to do it with regex?? else you can simply write `return text.contains(keywordInText);`

Comment: @Prashant Well that's the point; as said, checking if the keyword is in the text is NOT the problem. the problem is checking if it is surrounded by html tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Match {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String s1 =  "<h2> blabla </h2>"; 
        String s2 = " <h2> some other string </h2>";
        final String regex = "<h2>(.)*blabla(.)*<\\/h2>";  

        boolean b1 = Pattern.matches(regex, s1);
        boolean b2 = Pattern.matches(regex, s2);

        System.out.printf("the value of b1 is %b\n", b1);
        System.out.printf("the value of b2 is %b\n", b2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try Regex

```
(<h1>.+<\/h2>)  // Matches <h1>StackOverflow</h2>
```

**[Demo](http://regexr.com/3aksc)**